# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column calculator_calculation._id does not exist using heroku and djongo

Tags: python, django, mongodb, heroku, djongo

My app works on my local machine but when deployed to heroku with the exact same code I get errors when using get requests to my API views involving any DB interaction. I have a feeling heroku is trying to use postgres for some reason, even though I do not have any code dealing with postgres in my code. Any help is appreciated, I have done migrations a million different ways with no luck, even though mongo shouldnt need migrations.

Error and code below

```
2019-11-21T18:26:15.428986+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-11-21T18:26:15.428989+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
2019-11-21T18:26:15.428991+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = get_response(request)
2019-11-21T18:26:15.428993+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
2019-11-21T18:26:15.428995+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
2019-11-21T18:26:15.428997+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429000+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429002+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/calculator/views.py", line 22, in calculate
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429004+00:00 app[web.1]:     print(calcs)
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429006+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __repr__
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429008+00:00 app[web.1]:     data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429010+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 274, in __iter__
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429012+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._fetch_all()
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429014+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429016+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429018+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429020+00:00 app[web.1]:     results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429022+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429024+00:00 app[web.1]:     cursor.execute(sql, params)
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429026+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429028+00:00 app[web.1]:     return super().execute(sql, params)
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429030+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429032+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429034+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429036+00:00 app[web.1]:     return executor(sql, params, many, context)
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429038+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429040+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429042+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429044+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429046+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429048+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429050+00:00 app[web.1]: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column calculator_calculation._id does not exist
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429052+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "calculator_calculation"."_id", "calculator_calculati...
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429054+00:00 app[web.1]:                ^
2019-11-21T18:26:15.429062+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

I have everything imported correctly and settings are correct as far as I know for my mongoDB

```
import os
import environ
import django_heroku



env = os.environ

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)
# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'calculator.apps.CalculatorConfig'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sezzleCalculator.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sezzleCalculator.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "djongo",
        "NAME": "appDB",
        "HOST": "hostURL",
        "PASSWORD": "password",
        "USER": "randomuser",
        "AUTH_MECHANISM": 'SCRAM-SHA-1',
        "AUTH_SOURCE": "admin",
        "ENFORCE_SCHEMA": False,
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

It errors on this get request.

```
def calculate(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        calcs = Calculation.objects.filter().order_by("_id")
        print(calcs)
        calcsReversed = calcs.reverse()
        response = {"status": "1", "message": ("OK")}
        idx = 0
        for calc in calcsReversed:
            if idx > 9:
                calc.delete()
            response[idx] = {"first":calc.first,"second":calc.second,"operator":calc.operator,"result":calc.result}
            idx +=1
        print(response)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type="application/json")
    elif request.method == "POST":
        jsonIncoming = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf8"))
        print(jsonIncoming)
        calculation = Calculation(result=jsonIncoming["result"], first=jsonIncoming["first"],second=jsonIncoming["second"],operator=jsonIncoming["operator"])
        calculation.save()
        response = {"status": "1", "message": ("OK"), "type":"post"}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line in your `settings.py` (`django_heroku.settings(locals())`) overrides the `DATABASES` setting with what is in your heroku configuration.

Change it to `django_heroku.settings(locals(), databases=False)` and it will work.

Additionally: you shouldn't hardcode your production configuration in your `settings.py` file. That's what's environment variables are for. The Mongodb-Addon you are using will add the credentials to the configuration automatically.

You may check `heroku config` output, or the heroku dashboard.

Heroku itself tries to follow the [12 factor app principles](https://12factor.net/) and so should you if you are hosting on it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not see anyone else have this problem, but I figured it was heroku's addon somehow. Also I do not actually have the variables hard coded, I did hard code them one time just to make sure the enviroment variables were not off.